# Compiling error when using .value() for sending money between contracts using solidity and truffle framework

Tags: solidity, truffle, transactions, dao, reentrant-attacks

Dear fellow block builders! I am new to this field and I would like to implement my first project mimicking the famous DAO attack using re-entrance. I've programmed two smart contracts - the DAO and the Hacker. However, I could not get my contracts compiled due to the `.value()` method.

The DAO contains all users' balance, address and name

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract Dao {
struct User {
    address addr;
    string name;
    uint balence;
    uint8 flag;
}
....
function addToBalence(string name) public payable{
    if(users[msg.sender].flag != 1) addUser(msg.sender,name,0,1);
    users[msg.sender].balence = users[msg.sender].balence + msg.value;
}

function showBalence() public returns (uint) {
    return users[msg.sender].balence;
}

function withdraw(uint amount) public payable{

    if(users[msg.sender].flag != 1) revert("user does not exist");
    else if (users[msg.sender].balence >= amount){
        msg.sender.call.value(amount)();
        users[msg.sender].balence -= amount;
    }
  }
}
```

Hacker (currently just a normal user) is suppose to deposit a small amount first and later using the re-entrance attack to withdraw money more than his deposit at DAO

```
contract Hacker {
Dao dao;
address userAddress; // the address of the user, so the money can be transfered
string userName;

constructor(string userName, address daoAddress) public {
    dao = Dao(daoAddress);
    userAddress = msg.sender;
    userName = userName;
}

function addToBalence(string name, uint amount) public payable {
    dao.addToBalence(userName).value(msg.value)(); // ERROR HERE!
}

function showBalence() public returns(uint){
    return dao.showBalence();
}

function payout(uint amount) public payable{
    dao.withdraw(amount);
}
}
```

However, I got error at `addToBalence` method in Hacker's contract, where the prompt says `Member "value" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in tuple() - did you forget the "payable" modifier?
        dao.addToBalence(userName).value(msg.value)();`

I'm super confused since I already put the payable modifier at both DAO's and Hacker's contract. Does this mean my approach is way to simple and I could not attack DAO contract in my toy example? where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close, you just need a slight change in the syntax of your external contract function call in your `addToBalence(...)` [sic] function:

```
//...
function addToBalence(string name, uint amount) public payable {
    dao.addToBalence.value(msg.value)(userName);
}
//...
```

Notice that we dropped the first set of parentheses after `addToBalence` [sic] & moved the argument that was in there to the final set of parentheses instead.

---

Here's a full implementation of your contracts (with the `User` mapping and missing `addUser` function added back in in order to allow it to compile successfully) without that error message:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Dao {

    mapping (address => User) public users;

    struct User {
        address addr;
        string name;
        uint balence;
        uint8 flag;
    }

    function addUser(address _address, string _name, uint _balence, uint8 _flag) public {
        users[msg.sender].name = _name;
        users[msg.sender].flag = _flag;
        users[msg.sender].addr = _address;
        users[msg.sender].balence = _balence;
    }

    function addToBalence(string name) public payable{
        if(users[msg.sender].flag != 1) addUser(msg.sender,name,0,1);
        users[msg.sender].balence = users[msg.sender].balence + msg.value;
    }

    function showBalence() public returns (uint) {
        return users[msg.sender].balence;
    }

    function withdraw(uint amount) public payable{
        if(users[msg.sender].flag != 1) revert("user does not exist");
        else if (users[msg.sender].balence >= amount){
            msg.sender.call.value(amount)();
            users[msg.sender].balence -= amount;
        }
    }
}

contract Hacker {
    Dao dao;
    address userAddress; // the address of the user, so the money can be transfered
    string userName;

    constructor(string _userName, address daoAddress) public {
        dao = Dao(daoAddress);
        userAddress = msg.sender;
        userName = _userName;
    }

    function addToBalence(string name, uint amount) public payable {
        dao.addToBalence.value(msg.value)(userName); // ERROR HERE!
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I would never find that error by myself! Thank you @Greg for the insight and patience in reading this rather long post.

Comment: No problem & happy coding! Also, if you could accept the answer so others know that it's a working solution, that'd be fantastic!